# How to pass value into List in JavaBean?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, struts2

#### There is a JavaBean called TestBean.

- I want to pass some values into the List when I developed the java web. But I don't know how to do it.
- Generally, if only have List, we are able to use `xxx.add()` method (xxx is `List<String> xxx = new ArrayList<String>()`).

#### TestBean.java

```
public class TestBean {
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private List<String> options = new ArrayList<>();

    public TestBean(String name, String address) {
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public List<String> getOption() {
        return options;
    }

    public void setOption(List<String> option) {
        this.options = option;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your bean looks more like a data object. Beans tend to be stateless or tied to a session or other scope. They may depend on other beans or hold data objects when scoped, but your code looks like a data object, something that might be persisted to a database, etc.

That said are you asking for something like:

```
public TestBean(String name, String address, List<String> options) {
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
    this.options.addAll(options);
}
```

OR simply

```
public TestBean(String name, String address, List<String> options) {
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
    this.options = options;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:
1.Get List options property from TestBean.
2.Add elements to options.
3.Call the setOption() method and put options as the paremeter.

```
TestBean bean=new TestBean();
List<Sting> options=bean.getOption();
options.add("aaa");
options.add("bbb");
bean.setOption(options);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a List. Create a new TestBean object and use your setOption method.